# Powershell foreach $line considering the last match only

Tags: powershell, foreach, match

I am looking to list all matches but i am only getting the last match in the output file.

**Input File (ADO):**

```
TOTAL 0000002500
TAX   0000000000
TOTAL 0000001250
TAX   0000002520
TOTAL 0000006250
TAX   0000001820
TOTAL 0000007550
TAX   0000005820
```

**Powershell Script:**

```
foreach ( $File in ( get-childitem -name $ADO))
{       foreach ($_ in ( Get-Content -path $ADO))
          {
           # Declaring Variable: Total_Amt
           if ( $_.substring(0,5) -Like "TOTAL")   {
           $TOTAL_AMT = $_.substring(6,10)
            }
            }
            # iterate through ADO file and using above declared variables
        foreach ($_ in ( Get-Content -path $ADO))
         {      
          "TOTAL_AMT" + $TOTAL_AMT  >   $ADO_TMP
         }
  }
```

**Output File (ADO_TMP):**

```
TOTAL_AMT0000007550
```

**Expected Output File:**

```
TOTAL_AMT0000002500
TOTAL_AMT0000001250
TOTAL_AMT0000006250
TOTAL_AMT0000007550
```

**SOLUTION:**

I have resolved the issue by making a little adjustment to the script. 
Thanks for your help guys.

```
foreach ($_ in ( Get-Content -path $ADO))
{       
         if ($_.substring(0,5) -like "TOTAL") 
         {$TOTAL_AMT = $_.substring(6,10)
         "TOTAL_AMT" +  $TOTAL_AMT >>  $ADO_TMP
        } 
}
```

Comment: I have resolved the issue by making a little adjustment to the script. 

`foreach ($_ in ( Get-Content -path $ADO))
{  
   if ($_.substring(0,5) -like "TOTAL") 
   {$TOTAL_AMT = $_.substring(6,10)
   "TOTAL_AMT" +  $TOTAL_AMT >>  $ADO_TMP
  } 
}`

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the `$ADO_TMP` file every time a match is found with `>`. You need to use the append operator `>>`:

```
"TOTAL_AMT" + $TOTAL_AMT  >>   $ADO_TMP
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont think this is the problem. Now I see multiple lines though but with the same result.    `TOTAL_AMT0000007550
TOTAL_AMT0000007550
TOTAL_AMT0000007550
TOTAL_AMT0000007550
TOTAL_AMT0000007550
TOTAL_AMT0000007550
TOTAL_AMT0000007550
TOTAL_AMT0000007550`

Comment: I have resolved the issue by making a little adjustment to the script. 
Thanks for your help guys.


`foreach ($_ in ( Get-Content -path $ADO))
{  
   if ($_.substring(0,5) -like "TOTAL") 
   {$TOTAL_AMT = $_.substring(6,10)
   "TOTAL_AMT" +  $TOTAL_AMT >>  $ADO_TMP
  } 
}`

Answer (score 0):

You chould also use the `where` filter to get your desired output:

```
Get-Content $ADO| where { $_ -like 'TOTAL*' } | Set-Content $ADO_TMP
```

Comment: Didn't work. Got the same results I mentioned in my reply on the above comment **Script Modified to: **
`foreach ( $File in ( get-childitem -name $ADO))
{       foreach ($_ in ( Get-Content -path $ADO))
          {
           # Declaring Variable: Total_Amt
           if ( $_.substring(0,5) -Like "TOTAL")   {
           $TOTAL_AMT = $_.substring(6,10)
            }
            }
            # iterate through ADO file and using above declared variables
        foreach ($_ in ( Get-Content -path $ADO))
         {      
          where { $_ -like 'TOTAL*' } | Set-Content  $ADO_TMP
         }
  }`

Comment: I have resolved the issue by making a little adjustment to the script. 
Thanks for your help guys.


`foreach ($_ in ( Get-Content -path $ADO))
{  
   if ($_.substring(0,5) -like "TOTAL") 
   {$TOTAL_AMT = $_.substring(6,10)
   "TOTAL_AMT" +  $TOTAL_AMT >>  $ADO_TMP
  } 
}`